# String turned to Object when passed from client to nodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript

I'm using yeoman angular-fullstack to generate my project. 
So the client is angularJs (typeScript) and the backend is nodeJs. 
The problem is I got a variable and when I print it to the console, I get a very long string, (if u need to know its a photo_reference from googleplacesapi).
And when I pass it to the with a http.get to the nodeJS api, and print it to the log I get the response Object object.

MainController

```
    for (var photo of response.data.result.photos) {
      this.getImages(photo);
      console.log(photo.photo_reference);
    }
  getImages(photo_reference: string): void{
    this.$http.get('/api/image/' + photo_reference).then((response) => {

    });
  }
```

NodeJs

```
export function show(req, res) {

    console.log("photoreference:" + req.params.photoreference);
```

Comment: @mmm seems like typescript

Comment: Out of curiosity (not a solution), does it work if you explicitly cast to a string?

Comment: log the param without concatenating it to a string to see what value is passed `console.log(req.params.photoreference);`

Comment: since the argument passed to `getImages` has a `photo_reference` property it is an object so the logging is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the wrong value to the `getImages` function.
since the argument passed to `getImages` has a photo_reference property it is an object so the logging is correct

pass the `photo.photo_reference` to the function

```
for (var photo of response.data.result.photos) {
    this.getImages(photo.photo_reference);
}
```

Comment: thanks, now this was a silly misstake. Im blaming the late hours. :P

Comment: @JediSchmedi a second pair of eyes always help :)

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` will invoke `.toString()` in any objects you pass to it. The default implementation of `toString()`, for plain `Objects`, is to return `"[Object object]"`, which is stupid but also happily generic.

If you want to see the full structure of the object, `stringify` it:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params.photoreference));
```

You can ask `JSON.stringify` to render a human-readable version, using 2 spaces for indentation:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params.photoreference, null, 2))
```